# Regex, extract select text

Tags: regex, msdn, dngrep

I have a doubt about the [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) (Regular Expression) by Microsoft. I have a log file write in this mode.

```
2017-02-20 15:58:45.442 - [XYZ] 155 RADIO_TRAIN_TO_TRACK_INITIATION_COM_SESSION
                                  .VAR1p
                                  .VAR2o
                                  .VAR3i
                                  .VAR4u
2017-02-20 15:58:46.432 - [XYZ]   32 RADIO_TRACK_TO_TRAIN_CONFIGURATION_DETERMINATION
                                  .VAR1
                                  .VAR2
                                  .VAR3
                                  .VAR4
                                  .VAR5
                                  .VAR6
2017-02-20 15:58:48.541 - [XYZ] 158 RADIO_TRAIN_TO_TRACK_INITIATION_COM_SESSION
                                  .VAR1x
                                  .VAR2c
                                  .VAR3v
                                  .VAR4f
                                  .VAR5d
                                  .VAR6s
```

My question is: How i can extract all text from 2017-02-20 15:58:45.442 - [XYZ] 155... to  .VAR4u (include, so all text of message 155), and all text of the message 158 (timestamp include)

I have write this code but it doesn't run correctly

```
(?<=\[XYZ] \b155\b(?:(?!\n\d{4}-\d{2}-\d).)*?\n {3,}\.)|(?<=\[XYZ] +\b158\b(?:(?!\n\d{4}-\d{2}-\d).)*?\n {3,}\.)
```

Regards

Comment: What happens with the code? What MS application are you using?

Comment: @chris85: dnGrep. nonac, try `(?m)^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:[\d.:]+ - \[XYZ] \b155\b(?:(?!\n\d{4}-\d{2}-\d).)*` with the `Multiline` and `Dot as newline` option.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Aha, I wasn't sure about that last tag. I was thinking, `((?:\[XYZ] \b15[58]\b(?:(?!\n\d{4}-\d{2}-\d).)*?)(?:\n {3,}\..*)+)` no experience with dngrep though.

Comment: Well, in the DnGrep I have that .NET regex I shared does not work as expected. Try `(?m)^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:[\d.:]+ - \[XYZ] \b155\b(?:(?!\n\d{4}-\d{2}-\d).)*\.\w+`

Comment: @nonac, is that a bug? Do you receive any similar results?

Comment: @chris85 Thank you for your reply. But Wiktor's solution is correct to my goal. Thank you fof your time

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you! Your reply is correct for this example, but if i would a little fix to this [link](https://uploadfiles.io/ea98c). I tried this `(?m)^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:[\d.:]+ - \[RBC] +\b24\b(?:(?!\n\d{4}-\d{2}-\d).)*\.\w+|(?m)^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:[\d.:]+ - \[TRENO] \b156\b(?:(?!\n\d{4}-\d{2}-\d).)*\.\w+` to extract mex 24 and mex 156. But at the end of the line of both message don't extract all text. (As in this image [link](http://imageshack.com/a/img922/7337/65OHWm.jpg))

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hi, Wiktor, can i have an help with my last comment? Thank you for all

Comment: Try the one I copied to https://regex101.com/r/NBLDYy/1, I do not understand how regex is implemented in the tool. It makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DnGrep tool uses a weird .NET regex implementation: once you use a lookahead restriction, the last line is not matched. It must be a bug.

Anyway, what will work is

```
(?m)^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:[\d.:]+ - \[(?:RBC] +\b24|TRENO] \b156)\b(?:(?!\n\d{4}-\d{2}-\d).)*\.\w+[^\r\n]*
```

With *Mulitline* and *Dot as newline* checkboxes checked.

The `\.\w+[^\r\n]*` part is necessary to match the non-whitespace part on the last line (`\.` matches a dot, `\w+` - 1+ word chars, and `[^\r\n]*` will match one or more symbols other than CR and LF, can be replaced with `(?-s:.*) - a modifier group where the "Dot as newline" should be disabled`).

This part - `\[(?:RBC] +\b24|TRENO] \b156)` - is used in order to avoid repeating the whole pattern (as you did in your comment). That will match `[`, and then either `RBC]`+spaces+24, or `TRENO 156` (both as whole words as there is `\b` after the pattern).